# Dislocker error: "EOW information at offset 4b22000 failed to pass the tests"

Tags: automation, bit, ntfs, bitlocker, locker

I am trying to mount a BitLocker encrypted drive using Dislocker, but I am getting the following error:

Wed Aug 30 21:02:19 2023 [ERROR] EOW information at offset 4b22000 failed to pass the tests
Wed Aug 30 21:02:19 2023 [ERROR] EOW volume GUID not supported.
Wed Aug 30 21:02:19 2023 [CRITICAL] Cannot parse volume header. Abort.
I have checked the documentation for Dislocker, and it says that it supports NTFS, FAT, and exFAT formatted drives. The drive that I am trying to mount is formatted as NTFS.

I have also tried using a newer version of Dislocker, but I am still getting the same error.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried to mount a BitLocker encrypted drive using Dislocker. I expected the drive to be mounted and I would be able to access the data on it. However, I got the error message "EOW information at offset 4b22000 failed to pass the tests". This means that Dislocker is unable to parse the volume header of the drive.

I have checked the documentation for Dislocker and it says that it supports NTFS, FAT, and exFAT formatted drives. The drive that I am trying to mount is formatted as NTFS. I have also tried using a newer version of Dislocker, but I am still getting the same error.

I am not sure what is causing the error. I am hoping that someone on Stack Overflow will be able to help me troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: this is probably a better question for StackExchange, there's no code in your question